# Libgdx sliding screen transition

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a libgdx project with a Game as the base class and two Screens (my menu screen and my splash screen). I want, when the splash screen has finished, to slide the splash screen to the right and put the menu screen. I can just make an instant transfer using:

```
game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
```

but that dosen't include the sliding transition between the screens. I cannot find any website that tells me how to do this, how could I? I also have universal tween engine, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Saeed said u can use the TweenEngine to make simple screen transisitons.
Here is a [Tutorial](https://enplug.com/blog/animating-transitions-between-libgdx-screens-using-tweenengine)

If you need some complex transitions like sliding and slicing, you can take a look at a frame buffers and implement it your own way. The core thing is to swap between 2 frame buffers. While the transition is running render the two screens in a single frame buffer and then blend between them in the final rendering step. With this solution you are very flexible, but it takes more work and you can get in trouble, when using box2dlights.

I consider writing a small tutorial and update this post with it.

I suggest the Book: **Learning Libgdx Game Development**.

Edit: https://github.com/digital-thinking/libgdx-transitions

Comment: I followed the tutorial you suggested, but it displays a black slide over and THEN renders the next screen? How can I stop this?

Comment: I just did a pull request for screen transitions. You can see it here: [link](https://github.com/iXeption/libgdx).
I need to fix resizing soon, but i think you can use it untill i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

LibGDX doesn't offer animations for screen transitions .  You can create your own animations.
For example the screen gets blacker and blacker and when it becomes absolutely black set the next screen .And the next screen gets brighter from that absolute black.
Or you can use stages which I think are more comfortable for animations .